# How get specific string words in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string, algorithm

Assume I have following User DN 
And I need to get the only `DC` strings and value from the string below.

**Example 1:**

```
CN=xxx,OU=xxx xxx,OU=aaa bbb,DC=ABC,DC=com
```

**Result 1:**

```
DC=ABC,DC=com
```

**Example 2: Created by** [Sam J Levy](https://samjlevy.com/php-login-script-using-ldap-verify-group-membership/)

```
OU=Departments,DC=college,DC=school,DC=edu
```

**Result 2:**

```
DC=college,DC=school,DC=edu
```

Is there any way to get the whole DC strings like **results** above? 
[Sample Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w56jbuxd/)

Comment: What does jQuery/JavaScript have to do with it?

Comment: I just want to capture all the **DC** value only. Either can be done in PHP,jQuery/JavaScript. I have research on `split` and `explode` function. But I don't have any ideas to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP**

You can combine `substr` with `strpos` like this:

```
<?php

$string = 'CN=xxx,OU=xxx xxx,OU=aaa bbb,DC=ABC,DC=com';

echo substr($string, strpos($string, 'DC='));
?>
```

Output:

> DC=ABC,DC=com

*Example 2:*

```
<?php

$string = 'OU=Departments,DC=college,DC=school,DC=edu';

echo substr($string, strpos($string, 'DC='));
?>
```

Output:

> DC=college,DC=school,DC=edu

**JAVASCRIPT**

You can use this [strpos](http://phpjs.org/functions/strpos/) function with the `substring` and `length`

```
<script>
    
function strpos(haystack, needle, offset) {
  var i = (haystack + '')
    .indexOf(needle, (offset || 0));
  return i === -1 ? false : i;
}

var string = 'CN=xxx,OU=xxx xxx,OU=aaa bbb,DC=ABC,DC=com';
var pos = strpos(string, 'DC=');
var info = string.substring(pos, string.length);
alert(info);

</script>
```

*Example 2:*

```
<script>
    
function strpos(haystack, needle, offset) {
  var i = (haystack + '')
    .indexOf(needle, (offset || 0));
  return i === -1 ? false : i;
}

var string = 'OU=Departments,DC=college,DC=school,DC=edu';
var pos = strpos(string, 'DC=');
var info = string.substring(pos, string.length);
alert(info);

</script>
```

Read more in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
>
> http://phpjs.org/functions/strpos/

Comment: you help me a lot! Thank you very much. I'm still on the way to do it and I will look into your answer. :)